How to classify points in a QGIS shapefile by size based on a numeric attribute (tree canopy diameter)?
I'm using QGIS 3.28. I have a shapefile containing point data, where each point represents a tree, and I want to classify these points by size on a map. Specifically, I have a numeric attribute for each point that represents the tree's canopy diameter, and I would like to visualize the points on the map with varying sizes based on this attribute.
My goal is to have the points appear with different dimensions (sizes) corresponding to the canopy diameters, allowing me to visually differentiate trees with smaller or larger canopies directly on the map.

This : https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#graduated-renderer

thanks, that was easy. Can i use simultaneously the Categorized Renderer and the Graduated renderer? i would like to have both information shown on the map

Read up on data defined override of the symbol size.
